# Visual Studio C++ turn .exe +.dll into only .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a program that uses `libcurl` library. After code compiles in order for the .exe file to work I have to put `libcurl.dll` in the same folder as exe file. Is there a way to add this libcurl.dll file implicitly into the .exe file so it would not require the dll file?

Comment: There's a way to put the .dll into your .exe, as a resource. Unpack and load it dynamically (via, say, `LoadLibrary` or some such), google for it.

Comment: UAC puts a stop to that.  Packing files in a single executable is very common, surely you've used setup.exe before.  Or a self-extracting zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any payload to an executable image as a custom resource, including other binaries (see [Creating a New Custom or Data Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359082.aspx)). During application startup you will have to extract the .dll and save it to disk. This also requires that you mark the library imports as `/DELAYLOAD` (see [Specifying DLLs to Delay Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf3f62bz.aspx)). Otherwise the loader will fail due to unresolved imports.

A more natural solution to your problem would be to compile cURL as a static import library and link to it statically. This compiles the libcurl code into your final executable image. Instructions on building a static library can be found at [How to build cURL static library with SSL support on Windows](http://swatrant.blogspot.de/2013/06/how-to-build-curl-static-library-with.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using open-source [pefrmdllembed](https://osdn.net/projects/pefrm-units/) to merge the DLL into your EXE file.

**Commandline:** pefrmdllembed.exe -impinj myprogram.exe libcurl.dll myprogram_withcurl.exe

It will generate new "myprogram_withcurl.exe" that you can ship instead of the original EXE. Should work witb most DLLs.